# Получить историю powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Я пытаюсь получить историю команд в PowerShell.
Предыдущая сессия, к сожалению закрыта.

Я пробовал `Get-History` и один выдаёт только команды введённые в текущей сессии. Однако если нажать кнопку вверх `↑`, то он выдаёт команды из прошлой сессии. Можно ли как-то получить эти команды?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу как опубликовал вопрос нашёл ответ:

Вводим в PowerShell `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`
и получаем путь до файлика с историей.